# Data.Dequeue and BankersDequeue

Tags: haskell

Are there any code examples of how to use the Data.Dequeue module?

If I `import Data.Dequeue`, when I attempt to use the data constructor `BankersDequeue` I am unable to do so.

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m + Data.Dequeue
Prelude Data.Dequeue> Data.Dequeue.BankersDequeue 0 [] 0 []

<interactive>:3:1:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘Data.Dequeue.BankersDequeue’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      variable ‘Data.Dequeue.readDequeue’ (imported from Data.Dequeue),
      variable ‘Data.Dequeue.showDequeue’ (imported from Data.Dequeue)
```

Comment: That package doesn't export the `BankersDequeue` constructor. You can only manipulate it through the functions the module does export. This way, the user cannot violate any of the internal invariants that are always supposed to hold

Comment: I had failed to see that the export of `BankersDequeue` was for the type constructor, and that the data constructor was hidden. Since this particular dequeue has some very strict and complex invariants, I now see why this is necessary. I was then having trouble making one of these things, until I realised that the methods are polymorphic in their return types, so you can say the following:

`let q = Data.Dequeue.fromList [1..4] :: BankersDequeue Integer`

All is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

`Data.Dequeue` keeps `BankersDequeue` abstract by not exposing its constructors. That is indicated by there being no constructors listed under the [documentation for the type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue-0.1.12/docs/Data-Dequeue.html#t:BankersDequeue). However, there is a [`fromList` method in the `Dequeue` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue-0.1.12/docs/Data-Dequeue.html#v:fromList) that you can use to create dequeues.

Comment: @andro, you should edit your question to clarify exactly what you're having trouble with *instead of* asking for tutorials. Questions asking for off-site resources are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to figure this out as well

```
module Main where

-- Docs: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue-0.1.12/docs/Data-Dequeue.html
import Data.Dequeue as D

main :: IO ()
main = do

  let a = D.empty :: D.BankersDequeue Char
  let a' = D.pushFront a 'a'
  let b = D.first a'
  print b
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to others just starting using Dequeue.